# UIImageView stopAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview

In Xcode I've got 2 buttons: **Start** and **Stop**.

When you click **Start** `startClick`is called, when you click **Stop** `stopClick` is called.

When you click **Start** a UIImageView image will flash different images from the NSArray. When you click **Stop**, it stops, but I want it to stop on the image that was showing when I clicked **Stop**. At the moment it just stops and disapears... Any help?

Heres the part of the code:

```
-  (IBAction)startClick:(id)sender {

    color.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed: @"img1.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed: @"img2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed: @"img3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:  @"img4.png"],nil];     

    [color setAnimationRepeatCount: 0];
    color.animationDuration = 1;
    [color startAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)stopClick:(id)sender {
    [color stopAnimating];

    //What code do i put here to display the last image? (as i clicked stop).

}
```

I would also like to add if statments for if the color displayed is img1.png then do this... and if its img2.png do that...

Comment: put correct title ...it is good for other programmer :)

Comment: @user125697 I didn't add c++ tag....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will pause your Animation:

```
color.frame = [[color.layer presentationLayer] frame];
[color.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: it says: Instance method '-removeAllAnimations' not found (return type defaults to 'id')